# Trouble with flask pagination

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I have a block of looping jinja on a page, and I want to paginate it. I'm following [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/) tutorial, but I get "TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)." I think the problem is in passing home_data information, but I don't know how to do it. Here's my .py:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter

mod = Blueprint('home_data', __name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():

    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True

    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    home_data = Article.query.all()
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=home_data.count(), search=search, record_name='home_data')


    return render_template('home.html', home_data=Article.query.all(), pagination=pagination,)
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}

{% for dict_item in home_data|reverse %}

<!--<a href="results/{{ dict_item['id'] }}">-->

    <div class="photo">
        <img src="{{ dict_item['image_url'] }}" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="hometitlesstyle">{{ dict_item['title'] }}</div>
    <div class="voteorresult"><a href="votefor/{{ dict_item['id'] }}">Vote</a></div>
    <div class="resultbox"><a href="results/{{ dict_item['id'] }}">Results</a></div>

<hr class="new1">
    {% endfor %}

{{ pagination.links }}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using `home_data.count()` with no arguments. Apparently you need to pass one argument. What did you think `home_data.count()` means?

Comment: So in the tutorial example, it just has:

 users = User.find(...)

But I have no idea where they got "user" from, or what the equivalent is for me. I guessed   home_data = Article.find(...), but that didn't work either. I'm new to python, so while I know this might look obvious to an experienced programmer, I could really use a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `home_data = Article.query.all()` the `all()` turns the query into a python list. Use `home_data = Article.query` to keep it as query. That way the `count()` works on the query, not on the list.

Alternatively use

```py
home_data = Article.query.all()
pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(home_data), search=search, record_name='home_data')
```

Comment: Thanks! It's running now. Although now it's just running the tutorial's version of everything, it's not paginating my data. Hmmm guess I didn't actually understand this at all :/ All ears if you have any suggestions, but thanks much for getting it going!